# How to center an img tag into div tag when I resize the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and I love it, but I've have encountered a problem and I can't figure it out.

I really want my images inside of my div element to be like : http://jsfiddle.net/eb51hxj1/ when i resize the browser.

```
 <div class="divImage">
    <img id="image"> </div>
 <div>
```

My code is :

https://jsfiddle.net/a2bsarfb/

Comment: Look at the window.onresize event.

Comment: @David Don't do that please. We have CSS for these problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `var`
*<strike>less code and make more</strike>*

```
var divImage = document.getElementById('divImage');
....
divImage.style.backgroundImage = "url("+nextImage+")";
...
divImage.style.opacity = opacity;
```

remove `img` tag and put

```
<div class="divImage" id="divImage"><div>
```

and css
*`background-repeat: no-repeat`*

```
.divImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-image: url(...)*/
}
```

Comment: This works very well for me ! But with one problem. If i have an image with height larger then width, portrait image, the image is overflowing div. There is any way to limited the height?

Comment: @CarabusAlexandru you could put into stylesheet 'max-height: (reference-height);'

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox is your friend!

```
.divImage {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

align-items centers the div content along the cross-axis (vertically, in this case), justify-content centers the div content along the main axis (horizontally).

Remove one or the other if you so desire.

Comment: `align-items: center` isn't needed because it's only centered horizontally.

Comment: _only modern browser_

Comment: @avrilalejandro This is true, http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. IE11, Chrome, Firefox. Older IE's won't do it... but it's becoming increasingly unlikely that someone will be using an older IE. If this is an enterprise solution, I'd worry about it. Otherwise, I wouldn't.

Comment: @sethwhite Same :)

Comment: I changed the code using your method, but the problem is still in its place. https://jsfiddle.net/Hawksama/a2bsarfb/3/

Comment: @CarabusAlexandru Fixed it for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hyrumwhite/a2bsarfb/4/ You had set a width of 1200px on the divImage. This meant that your img was centered in your div, but your div did not fill the width of the page so it still looked off-center. I changed your divImage to width:100%, guaranteeing that the div would fill the page so that your image will be centered in both the div and the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the max-width of the .divImage to be 100%:

```
.divImage {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Just be careful of sizing, because the height will change to keep the size ratio the same. If you explicitly set the height, the resizing won't happen, but the ratio might look weird as you resize.

Answer (score 0):

Since block-elements always try to take up the full width of their parent you can use that to your advantage.

```
#image {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That's also how the Fiddle you linked did it.